Invalid Destination In SAML logout Request To IDP Keycloak
[org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-55) type="LOGOUT_ERROR", realmId="32008dd5-1b4e-40c7-a266XXX", clientId="null", userId="null", ipAddress="XXXXXX", error="invalid_logout_request", reason="invalid_destination"
I am getting this as Keycloak logs
at the keycloak configuration
ClientRequired Signature is off
validate RedirectUri's:localhost:8001/*
SP initiated Logout Request
I am sending my saml Logout Request in this way
http://127.0.0.1:8080/realms/OBSuiteRealm/protocol/saml?SAMLRequest=jZHdSsNAEIVfJex9uz9ZbTukAaUIharQihfeXXXXXXXXXXXX

My Xml SamlLogout Request
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Destination="http://localhost:8080/realms/OBXXX/protocol/saml" ID="_b60a71639553c975c4701XXXXXXX" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2024-04-22T12:10:31.722Z"><saml:Issuer>http://localhost:8080/realms/OBXXX</saml:Issuer><saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">esqxxxx</saml:NameID></samlp:LogoutRequest>

